# Applying constraints within a neural network?

Tags: neural-networks, constrained-optimization, multiobjective

I need to solve a multi-objective problem. I would understand if there is any kind of possibility to cope this issue through a neural network. Hypothetically, I need to put some constraints within calculation of a neural network. Is it possible? Is there any particular technique which could be used to address this issue properly?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What kind of constraints?

Comment: Basically, I have a time-series regression problem, with some variables in input which are predicted in the future through a NN. The predicted values need to be within specific boundaries (I have to define some constraints) and maximized with respect to another input variable.

Comment: OK... next question, why are you not using an optimization algorithm to solve this problem? Why are you trying to use a NN, which is not intended for this?

Comment: Because I've already implemented a system which predicts the values I need and I'm investigating if there's a way to include everything in a neural network, maybe applying a particular technique or approach. Thanks for you interest and help.

Comment: Hello, do you have any possible idea to address my issue? Thanks a lot.